# Where do I find a NPN transistor footprint library in KiCAD/How to import it

Tags: transistors

I have been trying to make a board that uses a 2N2222 transistor and I can't find any footprints in the library I also have not been able to download and import any libraries that work for this purpose, every time I try I end up with a blank folder, I am currently in KiCAD version 7.0 and using Ubuntu, how would I import a footprint from github into KiCAD

Answer (score 1):

Kicad 7 symbol browser. in search type 2222

[image]

From Wikipedia
[image]

In the properties for the symbol, you can change the footprint if you want the metal can.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have added the "Transistor_BJT" parts library to your project.

Unless you are using metal-cased parts you want PN2222A (this is the standard part number for the plastic version of 2N2222)

If you are using the metal ones, start with PN2222A and edit the footprint to TO18-3 and the value to 2N2222

Comment: I tend to agree that's the way it should be, but you can buy '2N2222's in TO92 case from many suppliers in China and India, just as you can buy surface-mount 1N5819 diodes.